# HTML editor vulnerability

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm doing a web shop and I have a little problem with description of product.

I want to user set his own description with some basic html element like `<b>`, `<iframe>`, `<body>`, `<style>` ,etc.

So how can I now protect that description from sql injection or malicious javascript and php code?

I tried with `myqsl_real_escape_string()` but I think that is not enough

Comment: Any code? Have you tried and tested anything?

Comment: I can think of pretty much no reason why product code, which will presumably be loaded into your shop template, would ever need `<body>`, `<iframe>` or `<script>` tags ... and `<b>` is pretty much obsolete (it has no semantic importance and in most instances where you might use it legitimately you'd probably be better off using `<mark>` with HTML5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `BB-Codes` for description.

**For Example:**

```
<?php

$description = 'hello, [b]b Tag[/b] for test';
$description = htmlspecialchars($description, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$description = preg_replace('\[b](.*?)\[\/b]','<b>$1</b>',$description);

echo $description;

?>
```

**output:**

hello, **b Tag** for text

Answer (score 2):

Protecting from malicious HTML is probably best left to something like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) where you can list what tags you're prepared to accept from the user.

There isn't really a safe way to accept JavaScript from a user unfortunately, because there are so many ways to mask the content that even running it in a sandboxed environment won't necessarily tell you if it's safe, so stripping `<script>` tags entirely is probably safest there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using PDO to run parameterized SQL queries,This protects you from SQL injection.

You can also prevent sql injection by using these techniques.

- Using `mysql_real_escape_string();`
- Using prepared statements
- Using PDO prepared statements

You can find more info about it here:

http://packetcode.com/article/preventing-sql-injection-php-security